# What's the best way to organize SQL queries?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, coding-style, code-cleanup

We have a couple of SQL queries as strings:

```
    public class Query
{

    public static string CreditTransferId(string expectedValue, string table, int statusId, int messageTypeId, int destination103, int destination202, string StoreStatus202Id)
    {
        return $"SELECT top 1 Id from {table} where MessageId = '{expectedValue}' and FlowId=3 and StatusId={statusId} and MessageTypeId={messageTypeId} and " +
          $" Destination103={destination103} and Destination202={destination202} and StoreStatus103Id is null and StoreStatus202Id {StoreStatus202Id}";
    }
}
```

We have them returned as strings from methods inside the `Query` class. We want to refactor the code, since we have a method with more than 3 parameters which is pretty hard to use.

How would you go about this? What's the cleanest way to organize SQL queries which need a lot of parameters?

Comment: The risk of SQL injection is extraordinarily high. Yes, this is just a method that returns a string, but it does ZERO checking on the validity of its arguments, uses pure string concatenation and no formal parameter definition ... it would never pass code review where I work.

Comment: just to clarify: there is **no** amount of validity checking that you should consider protects you from SQL injection; checking the inputs is purely to see that they are in your expected ranges; to protect from SQL injection, you absolutely should use *parameters*; Dapper is a very convenient way of executing parameterized queries if you like writing your own SQL

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic SQL is a very bad thing for a start as these are open to SQL injection, you should use parameterise queries and return a string.

`"eg: SELECT top 1 Id from [Table] where [MessageId] = @messageId"` etc

So you dont need to pass in any values, you would add these to your list of SqlParamater's

The table name is probably pointless as this is related to the sql, so probably just add that into the sql string

This doesn't really need an extra class, just create the sql variable where you call it, so it right there if you need it?

..or use Stored Procedures

..or use Entity Framework

Answer (score 0):

EF is great and you have to decide if that's what you want. There are some cases where it is not suitable. Of u decide to stick with plain text queries how about dividing queries into parts:
FromBuilder
JoinBuilder
GroupBuilder
Condition builder etc

ex.:

```
return @"
"+new TableIdSelectorBuilder(table).Get() +@"
"+new FromBuilder().Get(table) +@"
"+new TableConditionByIdBuilder(table).Get(I'd)+@"
";
```

EDIT:
Stored procedures allow to change queries without publishing new app version but is a bit pain in the ass to work on a living organism. At least sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps you a bit. I was figuring this out a long time ago too.

### Use nameOf instead of hardcoded column names

One advice that I have is: Try to use `nameOf()` for column names (in case your domain model matches exactly your database structure).

Refactoring becomes a lot easier as well.

### Create a query builder

I created a class which allows me to create simple to medium complex queries (Select, Insert, Update, Joins, Deletes, Limit, Offset, ...). For most of the queries that I write I can use this query builder to get what I need and the code will look something like this:

```
var query = new QueryBuilder()
        .Update(nameof(MyTable))
        .Set(nameof(MyTable.Name), entity.Name)
        .Set(nameof(MyTable.Firstname), entity.Firstname)
        .WhereEquals(nameof(MyTable.Id), entity.Id)
        .Build();
```

Unfortunately, I haven't found a good QueryBuilder out there yet. Therefore I created my own.

### Use string literals

[Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

Another solution that I recently encountered is by doing the following:

```
var query = $$"""
        SELECT * FROM {{nameof(MyTable)} 
        WHERE
        XX 
    """;
```

This at least allows you to indent correctly and the code will remain clean.

### Outsource your queries in separate files

I was also thinking about having bigger queries in separate files and include them in the Assembly. When you want to execute the query, you load the query from the file and run it like this.

You might also want to cache that query then, to not always load it from the file.

### Final words

- Personally, I try to use the QueryBuilder as often as possible. It creates clean code which looks somewhat like LINQ
- Backup approach for me is to use the string literals as showed above
- Trying to create separate files for queries, I have never tried yet, because there was no use for myself
- I would also avoid using Stored Procedures, because they are pain to write and also hard to debug in my opinion
- The cleanest option would be to use Entity Framework, but if you want to use Micro-ORMs like Dapper, try one of the solutions above